# Wait for angular to be stable, bevor continuing the test execution

Tags: cypress

I have a Web Application which I am currenly testing using Cypress. I have a problem That some pages executes client side rendering. after the page has been loaded / items has been clicked

I need to wait for the client-side rendering to finish, before the framework continues the test execution.

On the Console.

I need something like

```
 const testability = window.getAngularTestability(window.getAllAngularRootElements()[0]);
if (testability.isStable()) {
  doneCb(true);
} else {
  testability.whenStable((didWork) => {
    doneCb(didWork);
  }, TIME_OUT);
```

to work with cypress/typescript. I can not get the method getAngularTestability on the window object

[image]

I have considered using cy.exec but it seems to be executed on the system not on the app.

Comment: I think you want something like https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window#Start-tests-when-app-is-ready